# When i run the code i am getting this error

Tags: c#, asp.net, asp.net-mvc

I am getting this when trying to do using asp.net mvc

The parameters dictionary contains a null entry for parameter 'id' of non-nullable type 'System.Int32' for method 'System.Web.Mvc.ViewResult Index(Int32)' in 'Contr1.Controllers.HomeController'. An optional parameter must be a reference type, a nullable type, or be declared as an optional parameter.

```
namespace Contr1.Controllers
{
    public class HomeController : Controller
    {
        // GET: Home
        public ViewResult Index(int id)
        {
            EmployeeBusinessLayer employeeBL = new EmployeeBusinessLayer();
            Employee employee = employeeBL.GetEmployeDetails(175);

            ViewBag.Employee = employee; 
            ViewBag.Header = "Employee Details";
            return View();
        }
    }
}

namespace Contr1.Models
{
    public class EmployeeBusinessLayer
    {
        public Employee GetEmployeDetails(int EmployeeId)
        {
            Employee employee = new Employee()
            {
                Id = EmployeeId,
                Name = "aaaa",
                Gender = "Male",
                Address = "Alwal",
                City = "Hyderabad",
                Salary = 56431,
            };
            return employee;
        }
    }
}
```

I need to get the details on the web output but i am getting value to nullable or referenced or optional parameter

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You get this error because you require an id as parameter

> public ViewResult Index(int id)

Although you don't use it at this point you still require it. Either remove the "int id" or make the id nullable like this:

```
public ViewResult Index(int? id)
```